# Configuring Android Annotations v3.0.1 with Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

Configuring Android Annotations is quite irksome. But I finally figured out a solution and wish to share with everyone.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but could you improve the question so that it stands as Q&A format?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT. You can edit the question according to the 'Q&A format' and improve the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Use the below mentioned gradle buildscript.
>   Following are some of the references:
>   1) https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/blob/develop/examples/gradle/build.gradle
>   2) https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt
>   3) http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/21/androidannotations-setup-in-android-studio/

**build.gradle**

```
 buildscript {
      repositories {
      mavenCentral()
 }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.1'
          classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
      }
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }

 ext.androidAnnotationsVersion = '3.0.1';

 configurations {
    apt
 }

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 19
     buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
     useOldManifestMerger true

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14
         targetSdkVersion 19
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
     }



     buildTypes {
         release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
         }
     }

     packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

} 


apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName 'com.yourpackage.name'
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
    }
}
```